# Resolve a promise inside a promise

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck in a problem, i have a react-native app where i have a set of actions in order to display a video (i record those action before).

I have a for loop on all action and need to wait for the video to reach a certain timestamp in order to trigger the action. For that i use a switch to identify all my actions, and inside wait for a promise in order to trigger the action at the good timestamp.

Here is my code :

```
  isTimestampReached = (timestampToWait) => {
    console.log(
      `timestampToWait: ', ${timestampToWait}, currentTime: ${this.videoPlayerRef.controlButtonRef.getCurrentTime()}`,
    );
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (
        timestampToWait <
          this.videoPlayerRef.controlButtonRef.getCurrentTime() + 0.05 &&
        timestampToWait >
          this.videoPlayerRef.controlButtonRef.getCurrentTime() - 0.05
      ) {
        console.log('timestamp Reached !');
        resolve(true);
      } else {
        setTimeout(this.isTimestampReached, 100, timestampToWait);
      }
    });
  };

  previewRecording = async () => {
    this.resetPlayer();
    const {recordedActions} = this.state;
    console.log('recordedActions: ', recordedActions);
    for (const action of recordedActions) {
      console.log('action', action);
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'play':
          console.log('launch play');
          // if (await this.isTimestampReached(action.timestamp)) {  // this is the same as the line under
          await this.isTimestampReached(action.timestamp).then(() => {
            this.videoPlayerRef.setState({
              paused: false,
            });
            console.log('setPlay');
          });
          break;
        case 'pause':
          console.log('launch pause');
          await this.isTimestampReached(action.timestamp).then(() => {
            console.log('set Pause');
            this.videoPlayerRef.setState({
              paused: true,
            });
          }),
            console.log('pause outside loop');
          break;
        case 'changePlayRate':
          console.log('changePlayRate');
          this.videoPlayerRef.setState({
            playRate: action.playRate,
          });
          break;
        default:
          console.log(`case ${action.type} not handled`);
      }
    }
  };
```

and the log :
[image]

We can see that i'm staying inside the `for loop` and the `switch` because i don't get the `console.log('pause outside loop');` . But as you can see i don't get the `console.log('set Pause');` too. So this means my Promise did not resolve.

I think the problem is launching a promise inside a promise because for the first case (play) it work directly. But i don't see how i can solve this issue.

Thanks in advance from the community

PS: i've put only the javascript tag because i don't think this has something to do with react nor react-native.

Comment: why do you need the then you can keep the await and just have your update state below the await

Comment: Don't use polling in `isTimestampReached` (and in the `else` case, you completely forgot to resolve your promise)! Listen to the [`timeupdate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) instead.

Comment: Oh, I missed that you're using react-native not the html5 media api. What library are you using, doesn't it emit events for changes in `currentTime`?

Comment: i'm using react-native-video and i can have a callback on the time yes (onProgress) from the doc : https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video#onprogress , do you think of a cleaner way to do this @Bergi ?

Comment: @foufrix I would have done something like `new Promise(resolve => { element.addEventListener('timeupdate', function checkTime(e) { if (e.currentTime < timeStampToWait) { resolve(); element.removeEventListener('timeupdate', checkTime); } }); /* maybe also some error handlng */ })` but I don't know how to install/uninstall event listeners in react props.

Comment: i see what you mean, the idea is to have the currentTime triggered by a callback from the player instead of checking the time each time with a timeout. And the promise resolve only when the callback have the right value. I see if i can do that.
Performance wise it's a big difference ? Because it's either a callback each x times from the play VS a function that check every x times where the currentTime is, it's the same no ? @Bergi

Comment: Yes, perforancewise they would be similar, but I'd expect the currentTime listener to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This means my Promise did not resolve. I think the problem is launching a promise inside a promise.

Indeed. In the executor callback of `new Promise`, you call only `setTimeout` but never `resolve()` or `reject()`. The `isTimestampReached` call 100ms later does create and return its own promise, the original "outer" promise is never resolved. You could work around that by doing

```
setTimeout(() => {
  resolve(this.isTimestampReached(timestampToWait);
}, 100);
```

but with `async`/`await` it is much easier to do polling:

```
async isTimestampReached(timestampToWait) {
  while (true) {
    const currentTime = this.videoPlayerRef.controlButtonRef.getCurrentTime();
    console.log(`timestampToWait: ${timestampToWait}, currentTime: ${currentTime}`);
    if (timestampToWait < currentTime + 0.05 &&
        timestampToWait > currentTime - 0.05) {
      console.log('timestamp Reached !');
      return true;
    }
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 100);
    });
  }
}
```

(You can refactor that to use a nicer loop condition, but you get the idea).

Comment: this is working perfectly well, thank you very much @Bergi !

Answer (score -1):

```
  await this.isTimestampReached(action.timestamp).then(() => {
```

then will not get executed , as you await

use the below

```
const res =   await this.isTimestampReached(action.timestamp)

  this.videoPlayerRef.setState({
              paused: false,
            });
            console.log('setPlay');
```

or remove await

```
 this.isTimestampReached(action.timestamp).then(() => {
            this.videoPlayerRef.setState({
              paused: false,
            });
            console.log('setPlay');
          });
```

Comment: if i don't put this await, i'm getting out of the `switch` and the `for loop` continue

Comment: Using `await`  does not mean that `then`  doesn't work.